# GitHub API: List a users teams within an organization

Tags: github, github-api

In GitHub when viewing my organization's user list I'm able to see how many teams a user is a member of.

Clicking on this count shows me which teams a user is in, putting me on the following page:
`https://github.com/orgs/my-org/teams?query=%40username`

However, I'm trying to achieve the same functionality via the GitHub API, but I've been unable to find an endpoint that lists what teams (within an organization) a user is currently a member of.

One workaround is to loop through all the teams in an organization and get their members list, but this can quickly go through my rate limit, so to be able to do this in one request would be useful.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can do this with [GraphQL API v4](https://developer.github.com/v4/) filtering users in teams within an [organization](https://developer.github.com/v4/reference/object/organization/) with `userLogins` :

```graphql
{
  organization(login: "my-org") {
    teams(first: 100, userLogins: ["johndoe"]) {
      totalCount
      edges {
        node {
          name
          description
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

which gives for instance :

```json
{
  "data": {
    "organization": {
      "teams": {
        "totalCount": 2,
        "edges": [
          {
            "node": {
              "name": "Employees",
              "description": "org employees"
            }
          },
          {
            "node": {
              "name": "Developers",
              "description": "active developers"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Source : [platform.github.community forum](https://platform.github.community/t/query-teams-for-a-specific-user/4151/2?u=bertrandmartel)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, GitHub does not yet provide a way to do this.

At the moment, like you suggested, you would have to loop through each team in the organization to get all members within each one, then you would need to loop through all users, and check if the users are members of those teams.

You can increase your rate limit if you use an API token, but the solution is still lousy if you have a large organization.

Answer (score 0):

Heads up!
Providing an invalid/unknown "userLogin" sometimes results in all teams being returned.

Perhaps me doing something wrong, but I opened a ticket with GH about this, so lets see:
https://github.community/t/teams-userlogins-filter-is-not-working-as-expected/206251

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30065658)